Would a hybrid parliamentary system-military dictatorship work?
I am trying to make the government for an interstellar entity, and was wondering if what I came up with could work or would instantly self-destruct.
It's essentially a fusion of a standard parliamentary system and a term-limited dictator. There is a parliament that has full control of the country, divided into a normal upper and lower house(apportioned to each state and by population). There is also a small council of officials(normally from the military) nominated by the military and approved by the parliament. They have no power normally. However, the parliament can vote to declare a kind of extreme martial law either across the whole country or in just a portion of it for a period of time of their choosing.  For this time, that small council is basically a dictatorship with absolute control in that region until the time expires and parliament votes on whether to renew it or retake control. Additionally, there is strong cultural factors in this country emphasizing one's duty to their country, meaning that in general, people will try to act in what they think is best for the country(different people of course may have drastically different ideas on what that is).
The idea is that this keeps the advantages of a parliament while also allowing the country to react quickly in an emergency(like a war), keeping the advantage of an executive branch without having the disadvantages of it for normal operation. Would this work? I can see possible issues in the transfer of power, but would this system be stable and effective at governance?

Questions like this are a poor fit here. Stack Exchange is intentionally designed to help people find a solution to a specific problem. You're asking us to review an idea, which doesn't have an objective best answer. From SE's perspective, you already have an answer to your problem - you just want someone to tell you it's a good answer. To make matters worse, issues like this are highly subject to narrative necessity, which means it'll work if you write your story to let it work and it won't if you don't. (*Continued*)

... Do you have a specific problem you need help with? Is there a way to [edit] the post so that, rather than presenting your solution and asking us if we see any problems, you can focus on the problem that makes you unsure of your idea?

OP - just as a question - apart from the Hereditary aspect - how is this any different from the UK being a Constitutional Monarchy - Your Dictator (as you have described them) fulfills all of the functions as the Sovreign does in Britain - just the means of ascencion are different.

Originally a dictator was an extraordinary magistrate appointed by the Senate of the Roman Republic for a limited term (maximum 6 months) with full authority to solve a specific problem. For example, the famous L. Quinctius Cincinnatus was appointed dictator twice, once in 458 BCE (to lead the war against the Aequi), and once in 439 BCE (to put down the plot of Spurius Maelius). The system worked for about four centuries before breaking down. What more do you need?

@JBH I don't see how this is different from a "Does this work" question. What is the difference here?

@Bubbles "Does this work?" questions don't work here. People love giving opinions so they inevitably get answered, but to be very clear... your question is no different from "does this work?" questions which also are a bad fit for this site because we do not have a "review my question" policy in place and Stack Exchange's mechanics specifically and intentionally do not support such questions. VTC:Not About Worldbuilding according to the [help].

@AlexP -- Scalability?

@JBH Ok, thanks for the clarification.

I’m voting to close this question because the question is not well suited for the stack exchange

"Space is big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mind-bogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it's long way down the road to the chemist's, but that's just peanuts to space.” - Douglas Adams
Why is this important when it comes to governmental structures? Because a government can only govern territory over which it can exert a measure of control, that means it has to be able to communicate with its provinces and provide financial and materiel support in times of strife/conflict. Before you start to look at the structure of a government, you need to address how that government exerts and maintains control over its scattered subjects. Well defined FTL (travel and or communications) is kind of a requirement before interstellar government is even considered. The form of the government then follows function, i.e. your particular technological situation will place limits on what forms of government will work acceptably. Given what you're suggesting I would look at Frank Herbert's Dune for inspiration on governments that work across wide gulfs of communication and force projection delay.

There's also the art of picking out signal from noise in so much territory.

Well, yes, but that's not the question that was asked. He doesn't ask whether FTL travel is possible or how it would be achieved, or what color the uniforms of the soldiers should be either. You can't expect every post to cover every possible issue.

@Jay He did ask about governing an interstellar polity and in order to start answering such a question you first need to work out the rates and methods of communication and force projection, those put the hard limits on the range and degree of control a government can exercise.

Government works based on connections.
You can't just appoint someone a leader and have everyone obey them and have an effective government. It takes time to make connections. E.g. suppose the military wants more tanks. They need to know which factories to go to, how to motivate them, how to organize supply chains around them to get stuff done.
Same with the military. They have no connections or obedience to these random appointed bozos. Why obey them?
More logically, you have generals and high up army officials appointed, and they have business and political connections. When given power they are already used to it and can effectively command people.

Reminds me of the "keys to power" video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rStL7niR7gs

What you describe sounds remarkably like the Roman concept of a dictator. This was an official who received extraordinary powers for a limited period of time. Or like martial law in modern societies, except that they tend to give extraordinary power to the existing government.
So this has the potential to work out. It gets problematic when the holders of extraordinary power get used to having that power, and more and more situations get resolved that way. "If all you have is a hammer, every problem becomes a nail." Societies where martial law is involved too often tend to be crappy, which hurts industry and commerce, which damages interstellar commerce.

Also, when the holders of extraordinary power say "You know what?  I'm not giving this back."  See: Caesar.


I am trying to make the government for an interstellar entity, and was wondering if what I came up with could work or would instantly self-destruct.

I don't think this system would self-destruct instantly, but it would self-destruct eventually. With this system you're asking for military coups.
Like o.m.'s answer says, normally when martial law is in force the government gets extraordinary powers and it calls in the military to do the things it wouldn't normally be allowed to do. The government stays in control the whole time and the military remains a tool that the government is using to deal with an extraordinary situation, but no more than that.
In your system, the military actually takes over the government of a territory or a whole country during times of emergency. This gives the citizens of your interstellar entity an impression that the civilian government is not capable of dealing with emergency situations. When things are fine you keep the civilian government but when things go wrong you need the military to come in and clean up the mess. More importantly, it gives your military that impression.
In many military coups and civil wars started by the army, the excuse given by the leader of the coup was that this was done to save the country from a crisis. Here, you're making that excuse so much more persuasive to the population, and making it feel so much more natural to the top army commanders.
Let's say there is a prolonged emergency, like a war, or an economic crisis or something of that nature. Government hands over control to the military, it does some things to improve the situation. Then the civilian government wants to take back control because they feel things have improved sufficiently, but the army still feels the crisis is ongoing and they should stay in control. There is now a conflict between the civilian government and the military, and the military have the guns, or blasters and spaceships, and the civilian government doesn't. You can see how that's a problem.
Even ignoring the danger of coups, in many types of crisis you do not want the military making the final decisions. For example in a war they will probably be more likely to decide to fight a total war until the last drop of blood type deal, rather than be willing to negotiate a peaceful resolution.

As at least two others have pointed out, this sounds a lot like the system in the ancient Roman Republic -- before it became an empire. In times of crisis they would appoint a "dictator" (we get the English word from this Latin word) who would have extraordinary powers until the crisis was solved, or for 6 months, whichever came first.
For several hundred years the system worked. When a crisis erupted -- usually a war, I think, but I haven't studied this -- they would appoint a dictator, he would lead the country to victory, and then he would retire and the Senate would retake control.
Then Julius Caesar came along and demanded that he be appointed "dictator for life" instead of being required to retire after 6 months. This is what led to his assassination -- he had plenty of supporters who would have given him this position, and opponents understood that it would have meant the end of the republic.
Every democratic political system relies to some extent on the good will of the people in power. Suppose that a US president or UK prime minister or chief executive of some other democratic country declared that he was postponing the election and would remain in power until some current crisis was solved. He would surely have some supporters who said, yes, this guy is a great leader, we should keep him in power. Of course there would be opponents who would denounce him as a tyrant and say he should be arrested. So what would happen? I think it would depend a lot on what the military and law enforcement did. As an American let me use US organizations for the example. The whole thing could end quickly if the Secret Service marched into his office, arrested him, and escorted him out of the building. What if DC police tried to arrest him, and the Secret Service defended him? Would they shoot it out? The US military has an institutional ethos against getting involved in politics. So would they just stand by if there was growing chaos, or at some point would they intervene, and on what side? Etc.
Giving someone dictatorial powers increases the risk. He may decide that he likes being in power. Or he honestly thinks that he knows better how to run the country than the elected representatives, and so he has no choice to hold on to power for the good of the country. He may even be right in the short term. Maybe the legislature really is filled with fools and corruption and traitors. Again, think of any real democracy. Pretty much every country has problems with fools and corruption. What if someone came along and said, "Make me dictator and I will clean up the mess"? Some number of people would think that was a great idea.
